# Blender 2.9 importing MHX2 file IK not working

Tags: rigging, makehuman

When I import a MHX2 file from Make Human with a rig I cannot seem to activate inverse kinematics. I have tried Auto IK and manuel IK.
Any help pse ?

Eddy

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of the settings in the importer when you import?  Particularly those related to the rig, of course.  Which Make Human rig are you exporting and what overrides are you using?

Comment: Also, if it's a rigify rig, for each IK/FK setup there's a custom property that shows up at the top of the UI called 'IK-FK (mumble)`.  You have to set it to 1 to use the IK. Otherwise the FK orverrides.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Blender importing FBX and MHX2 files from Makehuman causes problems.
If I import a MHX2 file I cannot use inverse kinematics on the rig.

If I import a FBX file, in edit mode figure is displayed  90 degrees face down.

I have started exporting from Makehuman in DAE format and it has sorted out the problems.

I hope this makes sense.
Eddy